# how to hide a table view section on clicking switch in another section in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I am creating same setting page as iOS having and in wifi section when switch is clicked other section of network should hide and vice versa

Comment: Add some code pieces that you already developed and ask in appropriate ways what you are trying to do and where did you fail

Comment: refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061208/how-to-hide-a-section-in-uitableview

Comment: simply make a bool value in NSUSerdefaults and using that show hide you menus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many possibilities to implement such UI.

1.Either you can keep both buttons outside or above both tables.So that if you click on button1 you hide first table & show second & when click on second hide second table & show first table.

OR

2.In first table add two button at first row as you did.When you click on button1 then instead of hiding first table return 1 for table1 data source in numberofrows method & reload table1, so that buttons will be there & then show second table below first table.When user click on second button then hide second table & return new data source for first table & reload table1.

OR

3.Use one table for both data source.At first row there will be two buttons.On clicking on them reload table accordingly.