# How can I hide a section and its rows in a dynamic uitableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a dynamic table view with sections that I'd like to reuse in other scenarios, however only have certain sections shown. Is there a way I can hide an entire section so that my `indexPath.section` logic doesn't need to be changed when certain sections aren't shown? I know there's

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return 0
    } 
    return 60.0
}
```

to hide rows, I use that logic in a separate static tableView. But that still leaves the section header. Is there a way to do this where its seamless, as in hidden sections leave no blank space?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061208/how-to-hide-a-section-in-uitableview), you should be able to do this by returning `nil` from the `titleForHeaderInSection` method, and `0` from the `numberOfRowsInSection` method for whichever section you want hidden.